# civicrm 4.6 invoice documentation?

Tags: civicontribute

Is there any documentation available on how to generate the invoices with the new functionality introduced in civicrm 4.6. I assume I can generate and email an invoice but am not able to figure out how.

I have enabled TAX & invoicing in the configuration and have read the following articles:
https://civicrm.org/blogs/jamienovick/coming-soon-sales-tax-including-vat-and-invoicing-civicrm
https://civicrm.org/blogs/tonymazz/civicrm-46-will-support-sales-tax-vat-and-invoicing
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Sales+Taxes+and+Invoicing+-+Phase+1

Comment: have you generated Invoice ?? if not please read the below article https://civicrm.org/blogs/tonymazz/civicrm-46-will-support-sales-tax-vat-and-invoicing - this is the best document - still you have issue just let me know i will give you a clear documentation

Comment: I have no clue on how to generate invoices. Would you be able to let me know how to do so?

Answer (score 3):

The 4.6 version of the user guide should be published in the next few days (We are waiting for one more section to be proof read.)

In the meantime here are 3 images containing that information (I can't attach a PDF.)[image: invoicing part 1]

[image: invoicing part 2]

[image: invoicing part 3]

Comment: Thanks for the (upcoming) documentation, Joanne. I am running civicrm 4.6.3 and the print or email buttons do not show when I view a contribution. I have enabled TAX & invoices. Is there any other requirement for these buttons to show up?

Comment: I have just discovered that sometimes the buttons appear at the top of the contribution window, not the bottom.  Can you check there?  Also, what CMS are you using? Have you noticed anything unusual about the site?

Comment: I am using civicrm 4.6.3 with drupal 7.37 and unfortunately no buttons appear... !http://i58.tinypic.com/28sws37.jpg

Comment: I am running out of ideas.  It works on a Drupal 7 4.6.2 site I have access to and the drupal 7 demo site which is a little bit more than 4.6.3  (ie a few extra bugs fixed, but there is no bug fixed that would explain this behaviour).  My only idea is a problem with permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step Process - To print an invoice and also for Tax/VAT calculate

1. In CiviContribute component settings (Enable Tax and Invoicing)
   [Menu Link: Administer -> CiviContribute -> CiviContribute Component Settings -> Enable Tax and Invoicing]
2. Create new Financial Account (name: 20% VAT)
   [Menu Link: Administer -> CiviContribute -> Financial Account] 
   **Financial account type** = Liability,
   **Is Tax?** = is selected, 
   **Tax Rate** = 20.
3. Create - New Financial Type (name: products) 
   [Menu Link: Administer -> CiviContribute -> Financial type]
   **Tax-Deductible?** – is ticked
4. Now edit financial type (products) 
   Click on assign financial account. 
   Set - **Financial Account Relationship:** Sales Tax Account,
   **Financial Account:** Account payable
5. Then I got the new financial accounts assigned to the new financial type products
6. Now all the setting is done - create new contribution against the user for the new financial type (products) – and save the record
7. Now go for View the contribution – you will find a new button for Print Invoice - Click you will get invoice

Please use the link for reference https://civicrm.org/blogs/tonymazz/civicrm-46-will-support-sales-tax-vat-and-invoicing

Once invoice is been generated then you can go to find contribution select the contribution with invoice in the drop down you can select **print or email contribution Invoice**